# how to know if database relationship is made

Tags: mysql, database

How can I know whether my database relationship is made?

I am using MYSQL Workbench to design my database

[image: this is how the relation is made]

I am working on WikiPage so the "wiki" is something like a "Post".

the Problem is after i save it as `.sql` file, and import it into phpmyadmin, then when I open the design panel, no relation is made[[image: no relation is made[2]]

Whats wrong?

Comment: What storage engine are you using? e.g. InnoDB, MyISAM, etc. Some storage engines don't support foreign key relationships, so saving your table structure in the wrong format might remove the relationships.

Comment: @JohnEllmore definitely InnoDB